# SQL - Joining 3 table query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, relationship, join

Good day everyone,

This is my first post on stackoverflow. Honestly, the community is great and full of knowledge. I usually get on it but never made any posts until today I decided to register an account. I need the knowledge of this amazing community for a small quick join query.

For some odd reason I am not able to get it to work.

Here is the relationship table:

[image: Click here to view the relationship between tables]

What I am trying to output (In this example I will use userID 10):

Display tweet from the Tweet table of all the user the userID 10 follows (including the userID 10 itself)

In other words: Assume userID 10 is called Bob and Bob follows Bell and Rogers.

So I'd like to output the tweet of Bob, and everyone Bob follows: Bell and Rogers

Thank you in advance for your help and time :)

**EDIT:**

My apologies! Here is the sample data:

Sample Data

[image]

Thank you once again :)

Comment: Sample data in a tabular format would really help . . . and desired results.

Comment: You don't need user's data? Only tweet text?

Comment: Hanging around here so long, you must know how much we hate pictures of data! See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Thank you Strawberry for the link! Will definitely be using that instead of pictures :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sample data it's hard to be certain but this query should work. It selects all tweets from the table which match a userID (1) or anyone who that user is following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM User u
JOIN Follow f ON f.follower = u.userID
LEFT JOIN Tweet t ON t.userID = u.userID OR t.userID = f.following
WHERE u.userID = 1
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
tweetID     userID  tweet
1           1       Hello
2           4       Hey
3           1       Hi Folks!
6           4       Something
7           3       Heya!
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=694249d1616ef6717ba66e8666921672)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Nick, I am sorry for not being clear. The query is excellent although, what I want it to output is as follow: 

Selects all tweets from the table which match a userID (10) or anyone **userID (10) follows**

Comment: @Elbowham not your problem, I misread your question, the edit I've made should get it the right way around.

Answer (score 0):

This will select tweet text of the user 10 and anyone he follows.
Note that you need to put ID on 2 places.

```
SELECT t.userID, t.tweet FROM Tweet t
INNER JOIN
(SELECT following FROM Follow WHERE follower=10) uf
ON t.userID=uf.following
UNION
SELECT ut.userID, ut.tweet FROM Tweet ut
WHERE ut.userID=10
```

output (userID, tweet):

```
3   tweet2
2   tweet3
1   tweet1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select t.tweet
from tweet t inner join  
                  (select b.userid,a.following
                   from follow a inner join users b
                   on a.follower = b.userid) u 
on t.userid = u.following
where u.userid = 1 or t.userid = 1
order by t.date,tweet
```